# What is the Catholic understanding of what "God is Love" means according to the four senses of scripture?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, nature-of-god, love, 1-john

Until reading Dr. Peter Kreeft's [*Socratic Logic*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1587318083) chapter on definitions, I had no idea that "God is Love" (1 John 4:16) is a metaphor.  Quote from Section 4 (The limits of definition) page 129:

> As far as God is concerned, we can only say (a) what God is not or (b) what God is like. But this is not to *define* God, for each of these two choices violates a rule of definition. (a) If we use literal, univocal language, we can only say what God is *not*, not what God *is*. (E.g. God is not a man, God is not a body, God is
> not in time.) But God is not a negative thing, like nonbeing or death or evil. So a negative definition of God would violate one of the rules of definition (rule #5). (b) If we use analogical or metaphorical language, we can speak positively, but only to say what God is *like*, not what God *is*, literally. (E.g. we can say that God is a Father, God is Love, God is a King. But God is not a human biological father or the changeable human passion of love, or an earthly political ruler.)  And of course non-literal language violates another rule of definition (rule #3).

I don't really know why this blew my mind, but I had always taken those words and thought of them as literal (I still think they can and should be taken literally as well). And I've read a number of answers on this site recently that also take only a literal interpretation.

But according to the Catholic Catechism, there are four senses of scripture, so what have saints, popes, councils and other good exegetes, said about what does "God is love" means from a Metaphorical, Literal, Anagogical and Moral sense?  I'd prefer answers that hit on all four senses bullet point style unless there's a very good reason for excluding one.

Comment: Could you elaborate with how Kreeft explains "God is Love" metaphorically?

Comment: @eques it's a book about logic, not theology so it's not an explanation, Kreeft just listed it along with other things that are metaphors in conjuntion with God. He does say that (according to traditional logic) you can't essentially define God, so you have to rely on metaphors; maybe that helps.

Comment: Did he say metaphor or analogy? The traditional theology (Via Aquinas) is that because neither univocal nor equivocal terms can be used for God, analogical must be used.

Comment: @eques he definitely didn't say analogy.  But he wasn't talking about the specific classes of definitions; metaphor, essential, nominative, etc...  But maybe that's why John wrote "God is love" and not "God is like love"?

Comment: Some notes that may help: 1) "literal" in a logic textbook is *not* to be confused with *literal* sense of Bible interpretation; 2) that section deals with human language and human logic to capture divine reality using logical/literary concepts of literal/metaphor/analogy, which should *not* be confused with "analogy" as a theological method to understand God.  This is an interesting question (at least for me) because the answer needs to cross THREE (3) domains: language+logic, hermeneutics, and theology, each with their own method and technical vocabularies.

Comment: @grate I'm grateful that you added the quote, but I really don't want to pick apart Kreeft's logic unless it's necessary.  I only mentioned it because it struck me as strange that "God is Love" could be a metaphor and then I remembered that _everything_ in the Bible can be a metaphor.

Comment: @PeterTurner Please edit if necessary.  To me, the quote servers a warning that Peter Kreeft is dealing with ONE domain (logic) whereas the four senses of scripture deals with ANOTHER domain (hermeneutics) which also should be distinguished from the THIRD domain (theology).  Each has their own technical definition of "metaphor" and "analogy".  For answerers: this Q has to do with Catholic hermeneutics, see [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_senses_of_Scripture).  In the quote, Peter Kreeft only deal with domain #1 and #3, but not hermeneutics at all.

Comment: "If we use analogical or metaphorical language" he appears to be equating analogy and metaphor. I can at least explain how God is Love is analogy in the usual theological framework; I'm not used to that also being called metaphor

Answer (score 1):

In effect, this is a conflation of two distinct theological concepts: the 4 senses of Scripture (of which literal is one) and the necessity of analogy to talk about God's attributes.

The conflation is a side-effect of the particular language that Kreeft uses.

He contrasts "literal, univocal language" with "analogical or metaphorical language". The key theological distinction is between univocal and analogical. I have never come across someone qualifying "univocal" as "literal" nor someone equating analogical and metaphorical.

*univocal* contrasts with *equivocal* and describes what a word represents. *univocal* means the word has one meaning across the uses (= called one) whereas *equivocal* means the word represents multiple means across the uses (= called equal). For example, the word *bank* means can mean a place for storing valuables, the edge of a river, etc.

Aquinas argues in the [Summa (Prima Pars, Q13 A5)](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1013.htm#article5) that no name of God can be said univocally of God and creatures. The question becomes how do we understand statements like "God is good" (or "God is love"). It cannot be univocal as Aquinas says because God is simple and perfect and "all perfections existing in creatures divided and multiplied, pre-exist in God unitedly." In man, saying he is wise is distinct from his existence or power but in God to be wise is to be and to be powerful.

Nor can terms be equivocal because then we can understand nothing about God because "for the reasoning would always be exposed to the fallacy of equivocation" (Ibid.) That is, the situation would be two things that are called the same thing without any relationship between them. Thus, we couldn't say what it meant for God to be good from knowing what "man is good" means.

The solution according to Aquinas is analogy (or proportion) which is where the word is understood according to a proportion or casual relationship. The typical example is "healthy" which can be applied to a person or food or urine where in the first in means "has health", the second it causes health and the last implies a sign of health.

Analogy in this sense is literal; that is God really is good, just, love, etc -- we aren't using that phrasing to represent something else, unlike when we talk about the allegorical sense of Scripture. More importantly, his Goodness is more real than what we think of as goodness in creature because his is the source and cause of the goodness we possess.